# xcode/clang - "clang diagnostics ignored" get reported

Tags: xcode, clang, diagnostics

For cleanness of my code I have several compiler warnings, one of them is -Wextra-semi to report accidental ;;'s at the end of a line. However, some Google Maps macros do have an ; at the end so they end up with ;; at the end. To overcome this I thought "Let's just ignore it, it's third party software, I'm not responsible for it":

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wextra-semi"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

However, that still shows up as a warning in in the buildtime log:

```
While building module 'GoogleMaps' imported from /Users/edwin/dev/GC/Geocube/Geocube-Prefix.pch:43:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/edwin/dev/GC/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Headers/GoogleMaps.h:1:
/Users/edwin/dev/GC/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Headers/GMSIndoorBuilding.h:14:24: warning: extra ';' outside of a function [-Wextra-semi]
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN;
```

Is this because of the module-include parts?

The compiler is Xcode 9.2.